Python Session in 2nd gen Google Cloud Function - RuntimeError: The session is unavailable because no secret key was set
How can I use sessions in a Google Cloud Function 2nd gen?
When I try to set a session I get a error.
session['logged_in'] = True

Gives error:

RuntimeError: The session is unavailable because no secret key was
set.  Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and
secret.

main.py
import functions_framework
from flask import session

@functions_framework.http
def hello_http(request):
    """HTTP Cloud Function.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): The request object.
        <https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#incoming-request-data>
    Returns:
        The response text, or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using `make_response`
        <https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.make_response>.
    """
    request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
    request_args = request.args

    # Sessions
    session['logged_in'] = True

    # Hello
    if request_json and 'name' in request_json:
        name = request_json['name']
    elif request_args and 'name' in request_args:
        name = request_args['name']
    else:
        name = 'World'
    return 'Hello {}!'.format(name)

requirements.txt
flask
functions-framework==3.*


Does this answer your question? secret key not set in flask session, using the Flask-Session extension

@Edo Akse: This is not an Flask application (example running in Google Run), but a 2nd generation Google Function.

well you need to set the secret key, but since you don't have the Flask app object in which you normally use to set the secret key (as per above linked question/answer), what happens if you set the ENV variable SECRET_KEY as per this Flask doc and this Cloud Functions doc?

I tried to set the runtime environment variable in the Google Cloud Function SECRET_KEY to somethingsomething, but it still gave me the same error message.: RuntimeError: The session is unavailable because no secret key was set.  Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and secret.

Can you have a look at this Article.

@SandeepVokkareni that would not matter if flask.session cannot use the SECRET_KEY env variable

Can I ask what the desired end result is? There might be options besides using Flask sessions that manage to meet your expectations.

I want a user to enter a username and password, then save it as a session "logged_in". If the session "logged_in" is present, then I want to show the user the content.

The issue is that you're using Flask middleware without Flask, which doesn't work, as you've noticed. Technically it still runs Flask, but the app object in which you need to set the secret key is not accessible from your code, as it is managed by Google's behind the scenes magic that makes Cloud Functions work.
Depending on the security requirements, you can go as simple as creating cookies yourself. I'm not going to touch upon user management, only on reading/writing cookies.
Below is extremely simple logic to set and get cookies using Flask's Response class, as this is what Cloud Functions (CF) accept as valid response objects. I'm simplifying its usage as well by using make_response
import functions_framework
from flask import make_response


@functions_framework.http
def hello_http(request):
    # the line below returns None if the specific cookie has not been set
    cookie = request.cookies.get('logged_in')
    # test if user logged in:
    if cookie:
        # do other magic here, now just returning the string from the cookie
        # you should do some testing here that Flask Session do behind the scenes,
        # like actually testing the value of the cookie (which should be signed)
        return cookie
    else:
        # set cookies by building a proper response as per 
        # https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/write-http-functions
        # note that login logic should reside here
        resp = make_response("whatever response")
        resp.set_cookie('logged_in', True)
        return resp

First time you run the CF it doesn't find the cookie so it sets it using make_response. Second time you run the CF it will find the cookie and simply just return the value for it.

Please also note that you're using CF for something it's not meant to be used for, as per the CF use cases here. I would advice to use either App Engine or Cloud Run for this, as they are the more traditional serverless options, and better suited for managing user sessions. These also come with the proper safety features, like signing the cookie (which is exactly what you need to set the secret key for. Refer to this article for some more in-depth reading on this topic.
